# How to simultaneously interact with three multidimensional arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three multidimensional arrays with objects inside and 4 array recalculation functions

```js
function fun_1(val_1, val_2, val_3) {
  return val_1 + val_2 - val_3;
}

function fun_2(val_1, val_2, val_3) {
  return val_1 + val_2 + val_3;
}

function fun_3(val_1, val_2, val_3) {
  return val_1 - val_2 + val_3;
}

function fun_4(val_1, val_2, val_3) {
  return val_1 - val_2 - val_3;
}

arr_1 = [
  { x: 20, y: 20, moveTo: true },
  { x: 70, y: 20 },
  { x: 70, y: 40 },
  { curve: { type: "cubic", x1: 10, y1: 20, x2: 30, y2: 5 }, x: 3, y: 4 },

  { x: 90, y: 30 },
  { x: 50, y: 30 },
  { x: 50, y: 50 },
  {
    curve: { type: "cubic", x1: 50, y1: 20, x2: 10, y2: 4 },
    x: 45,
    y: 40
  },
  { x: 40, y: 30 },
  { x: 20, y: 20 }
];

arr_2 = [
  { x: 11, y: 65, moveTo: true },
  { x: 44, y: 43 },
  { x: 70, y: 33 },
  { x: 31, y: 2 },
  { curve: { type: "cubic", x1: 10, y1: 20, x2: 30, y2: 5 }, x: 3, y: 4 },
  { x: 530, y: 30 },
  { x: 2, y: 150 },

  { x: 253, y: 233 },
  { x: 212, y: 545 },
  {
    curve: { type: "cubic", x1: 50, y1: 20, x2: 10, y2: 4 },
    x: 45,
    y: 40
  }
];

arr_3 = [
  { x: 54, y: 123, moveTo: true },
  { x: 44, y: 41 },
  { x: 56, y: 14 },
  { x: 7, y: 2 },

  { x: 11, y: 2 },
  {
    curve: { type: "cubic", x1: 1, y1: 4, x2: 5, y2: 66 },
    x: 33,
    y: 11
  },
  { x: 55, y: 33 },

  { x: 66, y: 77 },
  { x: 334, y: 211 },
  {
    curve: { type: "cubic", x1: 7, y1: 20, x2: 5, y2: 4 },
    x: 45,
    y: 13
  }
];
```

I need to recalculate the entire array and then create an array with new data.

I tried to do it this way

```js
result = [];

var type = 1;

$.each(arr_1, function(index, val_1) {
  result_1 = [];

  var val_2 = arr_2[index];
  var val_3 = arr_3[index];

  //Проверка существования  curve
  curve_check_1 = "curve" in val_1;
  curve_check_2 = "curve" in val_2;
  curve_check_3 = "curve" in val_3;

  if (curve_check_1 || curve_check_2 || curve_check_3) {
    //Подгон
    cur = { type: "cubic", x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 0 };

    if ((curve_check_3 || curve_check_2) && !curve_check_1) {
      val_1["curve"] = cur;
    } else if ((curve_check_3 || curve_check_1) && !curve_check_2) {
      val_2["curve"] = cur;
    } else if ((curve_check_1 || curve_check_2) && !curve_check_3) {
      val_3["curve"] = cur;
    }

    result_1["curve"] = [];

    result_1["curve"]["type"] = "cubic";

    if (type == 1) {
      result_1["curve"]["x1"] = fun_1(
        val_1["curve"]["x1"],
        val_1["curve"]["x1"],
        val_1["curve"]["x1"]
      );
      result_1["curve"]["y1"] = fun_1(
        val_1["curve"]["y1"],
        val_1["curve"]["y1"],
        val_1["curve"]["y1"]
      );
      result_1["curve"]["x2"] = fun_1(
        val_1["curve"]["x2"],
        val_1["curve"]["x2"],
        val_1["curve"]["x2"]
      );
      result_1["curve"]["y2"] = fun_1(
        val_1["curve"]["y2"],
        val_1["curve"]["y2"],
        val_1["curve"]["y2"]
      );
    } else if (type == 2) {
      result_1["curve"]["x1"] = fun_2(
        val_1["curve"]["x1"],
        val_1["curve"]["x1"],
        val_1["curve"]["x1"]
      );
      result_1["curve"]["y1"] = fun_2(
        val_1["curve"]["y1"],
        val_1["curve"]["y1"],
        val_1["curve"]["y1"]
      );
      result_1["curve"]["x2"] = fun_2(
        val_1["curve"]["x2"],
        val_1["curve"]["x2"],
        val_1["curve"]["x2"]
      );
      result_1["curve"]["y2"] = fun_2(
        val_1["curve"]["y2"],
        val_1["curve"]["y2"],
        val_1["curve"]["y2"]
      );
    } else if (type == 3) {
      result_1["curve"]["x1"] = fun_3(
        val_1["curve"]["x1"],
        val_1["curve"]["x1"],
        val_1["curve"]["x1"]
      );
      result_1["curve"]["y1"] = fun_3(
        val_1["curve"]["y1"],
        val_1["curve"]["y1"],
        val_1["curve"]["y1"]
      );
      result_1["curve"]["x2"] = fun_3(
        val_1["curve"]["x2"],
        val_1["curve"]["x2"],
        val_1["curve"]["x2"]
      );
      result_1["curve"]["y2"] = fun_3(
        val_1["curve"]["y2"],
        val_1["curve"]["y2"],
        val_1["curve"]["y2"]
      );
    } else if (type == 4) {
      result_1["curve"]["x1"] = fun_4(
        val_1["curve"]["x1"],
        val_1["curve"]["x1"],
        val_1["curve"]["x1"]
      );
      result_1["curve"]["y1"] = fun_4(
        val_1["curve"]["y1"],
        val_1["curve"]["y1"],
        val_1["curve"]["y1"]
      );
      result_1["curve"]["x2"] = fun_4(
        val_1["curve"]["x2"],
        val_1["curve"]["x2"],
        val_1["curve"]["x2"]
      );
      result_1["curve"]["y2"] = fun_4(
        val_1["curve"]["y2"],
        val_1["curve"]["y2"],
        val_1["curve"]["y2"]
      );
    }
  }

  if (type == 1) {
    result_1["x"] = fun_1(val_1["x"], val_2["x"], val_3["x"]);
    result_1["y"] = fun_1(val_1["y"], val_2["y"], val_3["y"]);
  } else if (type == 2) {
    result_1["x"] = fun_2(val_1["x"], val_2["x"], val_3["x"]);
    result_1["y"] = fun_2(val_1["y"], val_2["y"], val_3["y"]);
  } else if (type == 3) {
    result_1["x"] = fun_3(val_1["x"], val_2["x"], val_3["x"]);
    result_1["y"] = fun_3(val_1["y"], val_2["y"], val_3["y"]);
  } else if (type == 4) {
    result_1["x"] = fun_4(val_1["x"], val_2["x"], val_3["x"]);
    result_1["y"] = fun_4(val_1["y"], val_2["y"], val_3["y"]);
  }

  result.push(result_1);
});

console.log(arr_1);

console.log(result);
```

But for some reason, I can’t do it right either. Can anyone help me with this?

the result should be something like this for [fun_2](https://ibb.co/kD11YZc)

Comment: They don't look like multi-dimensional arrays, but arrays of objects.

Comment: "*I need to recalculate the entire array and then create an array with new data.*" - sounds suitably vague.  "recalculate" how?  What should be in the new array(/object)?  Can't see where `type` is changed, so your function is `return arr_1`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the desired result you have mentioned [here](https://ibb.co/kD11YZc) for **fun_2**, I have tried changing the code for executing **fun_2** with **type==2**. Here is the part of the code that I have modified:

```
else if (type == 2){

result_1['curve']['x1'] = fun_2(val_1['curve'] && val_1['curve']['x1']  || 0, 
                               val_2['curve'] && val_2['curve']['x1'] || 0, 
                               val_3['curve'] && val_3['curve']['x1'] || 0);

result_1['curve']['y1'] = fun_2(val_1['curve'] && val_1['curve']['y1']  || 0, 
                                val_2['curve'] && val_2['curve']['y1'] || 0, 
                                val_3['curve'] && val_3['curve']['y1'] || 0);

result_1['curve']['x2'] = fun_2(val_1['curve'] && val_1['curve']['x2']  || 0, 
                                val_2['curve'] && val_2['curve']['x2'] || 0, 
                                val_3['curve'] && val_3['curve']['x2'] || 0);

result_1['curve']['y2'] = fun_2(val_1['curve'] && val_1['curve']['y2']  || 0, 
                                val_2['curve'] && val_2['curve']['y2'] || 0, 
                                val_3['curve'] && val_3['curve']['y2'] || 0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

code from [@teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223826/teran)

```js
function pm(a,b,c){ return a + b - c; }
function pp(a,b,c){ return a + b + c; }
function mp(a,b,c){ return a - b + c; }
function mm(a,b,c){ return a - b - c; }


const arr_1 = [{x:20,y:20,moveTo:true},{x:70,y:20},{x:70,y:40},{curve:{type:"cubic",x1:10,y1:20,x2:30,y2:5},x:3,y:4},{x:90,y:30},{x:50,y:30},{x:50,y:50},{curve:{type:"cubic",x1:50,y1:20,x2:10,y2:4},x:45,y:40},{x:40,y:30},{x:20,y:20}];
const arr_2 = [{x:11,y:65,moveTo:true},{x:44,y:43},{x:70,y:33},{x:31,y:2},{curve:{type:"cubic",x1:10,y1:20,x2:30,y2:5},x:3,y:4},{x:530,y:30},{x:2,y:150},{x:253,y:233},{x:212,y:545},{curve:{type:"cubic",x1:50,y1:20,x2:10,y2:4},x:45,y:40}];
const arr_3 = [{x:54,y:123,moveTo:true},{x:44,y:41},{x:56,y:14},{x:7,y:2},{x:11,y:2},{curve:{type:"cubic",x1:1,y1:4,x2:5,y2:66},x:33,y:11},{x:55,y:33},{x:66,y:77},{x:334,y:211},{curve:{type:"cubic",x1:7,y1:20,x2:5,y2:4},x:45,y:13}];


var result = [];
var func = pp;


for(let idx = 0; idx < arr_1.length; idx++){
    const a = arr_1[idx],
          b = arr_2[idx],
          c = arr_3[idx]; 
          
    const curve = a.curve || b.curve || c.curve;         

    var item =  { };   
    
    if(curve){
        const points = ['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2'];
        item.curve = { type: 'cubic' };
       
        let cp = (v,p) => v.curve ? v.curve[p] : 0;
       
        points.forEach(function(p){
            item.curve[p] = func(cp(a,p), cp(b,p), cp(c,p));
        });    
    }
 
    item.x = func(a.x, b.x, c.x);
    item.y = func(a.y, b.y, c.y);
    if(a.moveTo){
        item.moveTo = a.moveTo;
    }

 
    result.push(item);
} 

console.log(result);
```